# Pandas - Align column subset rows with matching values in master column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am starting out with the following dataframe (df):

```
  variable  key  i  j  k
0        a    1  0  0  0
1        a    2  0  0  0
2        a    3  0  0  0
3        b    2  0  0  0
4        c    1  0  0  0
5        c    3  0  0  0
```

Using the following code, I transform it into the 2nd displayed dataframe (out).

```
out = pd.DataFrame()
out['keys_master'] = list(range(min(df['key']), max(df['key']) + 1))
for value in ['a', 'b', 'c']:
    temp = df.loc[df[variable_string] == value]
    cols = [f'{i}{value}' for i in df.columns.values]
    temp.columns = cols
    out = pd.concat([out, temp], axis=1)

    # Drop columns that contain variable names, then drop empty rows
    out.drop(columns=cols[0], inplace=True)
    out.dropna(axis=0, how='all', inplace=True)
```

out:

```
   keys_master  keya   ia   ja   ka  keyb   ib   jb   kb  keyc   ic   jc   kc
0          1.0   1.0  0.0  0.0  0.0   NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN   NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
1          2.0   2.0  0.0  0.0  0.0   NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN   NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
2          3.0   3.0  0.0  0.0  0.0   NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN   NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
3          NaN   NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN   2.0  0.0  0.0  0.0   NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
4          NaN   NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN   NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN   1.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
5          NaN   NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN   NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN   3.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
```

How can I transform out into a dataframe like this?

```
   keys_master  keya  ia  ja  ka  keyb  ib  jb  kb  keyc  ic  jc  kc
0          1.0   1.0 0.0 0.0 0.0   NaN NaN NaN NaN   1.0 0.0 0.0 0.0
1          2.0   2.0 0.0 0.0 0.0   2.0 0.0 0.0 0.0   NaN NaN NaN NaN
2          3.0   3.0 0.0 0.0 0.0   NaN NaN NaN NaN   3.0 0.0 0.0 0.0
```

Comment: How did you get this dataframe? Seems like it would be easier to build the dataframe correctly the first time rather than trying to post-process the results.

Comment: Sorry the original question didn't have enough context. I updated it to show how I got the dataframe.

Answer (score 2):

Similar to the original approach of grouping together and concating. We can use [`set_index`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) to assign `key` as the index which will allow for easy alignment then [`groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) to create a dictionary of DataFrames which can be [`concat`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.concat.html):

```
d = dict(tuple(df.set_index('key', drop=False).groupby('variable')))
out = pd.concat(d, axis=1)
```

`out`:

```
           a                     b                            c                    
    variable key  i  j  k variable  key    i    j    k variable  key    i    j    k
key                                                                                
1          a   1  0  0  0      NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN        c  1.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
2          a   2  0  0  0        b  2.0  0.0  0.0  0.0      NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
3          a   3  0  0  0      NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN        c  3.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
```

---

With a little bit of cleanup we can match the expected output:

1. [`drop`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop.html) to get rid of the variable column (since this data has been moved to the header
2. [`rename_axis`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rename_axis.html) to make index name `keys_master` instead of `keys`
3. [`swaplevel`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.swaplevel.html) to make collapsing the MultiIndex easier
4. [`reset_index`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html) to restore the RangeIndex and make `keys_master` a column
5. [`Index.map`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Index.map.html) to collapse the MultiIndex into a single level

```
out = (
    pd.concat(
        dict(tuple(df.set_index('key', drop=False).groupby('variable'))),
        axis=1
    ).drop('variable', axis=1, level=1)
        .rename_axis(index='keys_master')
        .swaplevel(axis=1)
        .reset_index()
)
out.columns = out.columns.map(''.join)
```

`out`:

```
   keys_master  keya  ia  ja  ka  keyb   ib   jb   kb  keyc   ic   jc   kc
0            1     1   0   0   0   NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN   1.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
1            2     2   0   0   0   2.0  0.0  0.0  0.0   NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
2            3     3   0   0   0   NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN   3.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
```

---

However, it can be much more simply achieved with [`pivot`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html) and [`sort_index`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_index.html) assuming `key` `variable` relationship is unqiue:

```
out = (
    # Duplicate key column
    df.assign(keys_master=df['key'])
        # Pivot to make variable the columns aligned on keys_master
        .pivot(index='keys_master', columns='variable')
        # Sort index level 1 so variable is grouped together
        .sort_index(level=1, axis=1, sort_remaining=False)
        # Restore RangeIndex and make keys_master a column again
        .reset_index()
)
# Collapse MultiIndex
out.columns = out.columns.map(''.join)
```

`out`:

```
   keys_master  keya   ia   ja   ka  keyb   ib   jb   kb  keyc   ic   jc   kc
0            1   1.0  0.0  0.0  0.0   NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN   1.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
1            2   2.0  0.0  0.0  0.0   2.0  0.0  0.0  0.0   NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
2            3   3.0  0.0  0.0  0.0   NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN   3.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
```

Comment: Perfect! Thank you very much sir.